# Change ReSharper inspection severity once

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I want to change inspection severity for one case

Say i have an enum

```
enum MyEnum { First, Second, Third }
```

and then a switch

```
void Foo(MyEnum value)
{
    // Looking for something like
    // Resharper once severity:error SwitchStatementMissingSomeCases
    switch (value)
    {
        case MyEnum.First:
            // do something
            break;
        case MyEnum.Second:
            // do something else
            break;
        // <<< Missing MyEnum.Third
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

I want this code to produce a compilation error. Is it possible?

I understand it is possible to do something like code below, but i want to know there is a missing case at compile time

```
void Bar()
{
    // do something
}

void Baz()
{
    // do something else
}

Dictionary<MyEnum, Action> Handlers = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Action>
{
    [MyEnum.First] = Bar
    [MyEnum.Second] = Baz
}

void Foo(MyEnum value)
{
    if (! Handlers.TryGetValue(value, out Action action))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    action();
}
```

**UPD**: I **don't** want to set global inspection severity

**UPD2** I have like 50 switches (on other enums) where missing case is not a big deal and just a couple of switches where missing case should be a compilation error. It's possible to set global level to error and disable error 50 times, but... a bit ugly

**UPD3** Unfortunately there is no way to do it now (22.05.2018)
[Comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467497/change-resharper-inspection-severity-once#comment87948816_50467763)
[Comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467497/change-resharper-inspection-severity-once#comment87948822_50467497)

Comment: Possible duplicate (assuming this works in Resharper) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932520/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-c-sharp-compiler-to-emit-an-error-if-a-switchenum-val

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, but you can configure the inspection to be skipped once, for the whole file, or globally.

Just click on the Resharper Bulb, you can also configure that this is a compilation error when there is a switch case missing

Comment: I think there is no way to do that, inspection severity is global. Maybe you can create custom inspection for this case.

Comment: @Evk Ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it now (22.05.2018) with simple comment

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just have to click on the Resharper bulb and configure it to add the missing cases and the severity (Error), 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this will change global severity level, i want to change it for this particular case

Comment: So, what do you want exactly is to configure the inspection severity to compiler error but just for this case? That is not possible right now in resharper.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i wanted. That's sad :( Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Well, it doesn't really make sense to configure that in some scopes and not in others.
You can maybe configure it globally to error and skip the inspection in the others switch cases.
You can also create you own custom inspection for that case:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html